# Google ads only appear on home page

Tags: adsense

Great mind and great people, i need someone to help.
I have this blog hosted with blogspot with custom domain name, with adsense on it. but google ads only appear on homepage and not on any other page or post. what could be the solution? Thanks

Comment: did you check that your google hash code is the same in all them?

Comment: And did you check that you are loding the js needed in all the subpages?